# send variable with ajax when load page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

try setting my code for send variable from view to controller,but my code is not run and show error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

**view**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var st = $('#st').val();
    var postdata = { st: st };
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '<?= base_url();?>task_tickets/tes',
      data: postdata,
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

**controller**

```
function cek(){
     echo $st;
}
```

Comment: Have you included `jquery` js file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery - $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like either you have not included jQuery plugin or added after your JavaScript code. $ is alias to jQuery.
In your view before script tag, include this

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.js"></script>`